# Convert break line to array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to convert my config content to array.

This is my config content:

```
echo Executing Server Config...
lanmode 0
rcon_password dadasdasdsad
maxplayers 10
port 11494
hostname SA-MP 0.3 Server
gamemode0 grandlarc 1
filterscripts base gl_actions gl_property gl_realtime
announce 0
query 1
weburl www.sa-mp.com
maxnpc 0
onfoot_rate 40
incar_rate 40
weapon_rate 40
stream_distance 300.0
stream_rate 1000
```

i want convert this to array like this :

```
$array['lanmode'] // value is 0
$array['rcon_password'] // value is dadasdasdsad
...
```

so how i can do this, thanks everyone and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `explode()` twice: once to get each line, then once to get each element.

```
$config = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $configstring) as $v) {
    $exp = explode(" ", $v);
    $config[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
}
```

Where `$configstring` is your config as given above (without the first line).

Output of `$config`:

```
Array
(
    [lanmode] => 0
    [rcon_password] => dadasdasdsad
    [maxplayers] => 10
    [port] => 11494
    [hostname] => SA-MP
    [gamemode0] => grandlarc
    [filterscripts] => base
    [announce] => 0
    [query] => 1
    [weburl] => www.sa-mp.com
    [maxnpc] => 0
    [onfoot_rate] => 40
    [incar_rate] => 40
    [weapon_rate] => 40
    [stream_distance] => 300.0
    [stream_rate] => 1000
)
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/dqSRH)

---

If you want to get rid of the first line, like you have "*Executing Server Config...*" at the top, you can just `unset()` the first piece of the array after exploding, like this

```
$config = array();
$exploded = explode("\n", $configstring);
unset($exploded[0]);
foreach ($exploded as $v) {
    $exp = explode(" ", $v);
    $config[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
}
```

[**Live demo** with removal of first line](https://3v4l.org/1Jmn1)

---

- http://php.net/explode

Comment: Thanks you so much !